# Openlayers Click event

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, gis

I work with Openlayers and I want to catch feature click event and Map click event. If feature exists I want only feature click event and if feature not exists I want Map click event,

```
self.baseMap = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: self.divId,
    allOverlays: true,
    layers: [
        baseLayer
    ],
    eventListeners: {
        featureclick: function(e) {
            //Click 
            return false;
        }
    }
});
self.baseMap.events.register('click', self.baseMap, function(e) {
   //Click 
});
```

I feature Exists I have feature click event and Map click event . return false, stoppropagation() and preventdefault() not working

Answer (score 0):

Feature click event only works when there is a feature on the vector layer and you add your listener to that (vector) layer (look at selectFeature control). Then you have two listeners and you can handle their behaviour separately...